# How to display calculated info from a file to a graphics window in python?

Tags: python

I want to output something that involves information from a datafile to a graphics window. The datafile looks something like this;

```
Force    Displacement    Theta
0        0               0
15       0               0
3        0.15            0
1        1               90
-3       0.15            0
```

My code in python looks something like;

```
input = Entry(Point(9,7.5),5)
output = Text(Point(x,y)," ")
output.draw(win)

def parse(line):
    return(float(token) for token in line.split())

def work(F, d, theta):
    return F * d * cos(radians(theta))

fname  = inputgetText()

with open(fname, 'r') as infile:
     infile.readline()
     for line in infile:
         f,d,t = parse(line)
         output.setText(("%.2f") % work(f,d,t))
```

When I run the script, the result is not what I want. I expected the answers for all the lines in the datafile but instead I only got one. I need help to know how to get the answers for all the lines instead of just one.

Thank you for whoever saves me from failing